# Excluding dependencies/jars from jdk

Tags: spring, email, maven, spring-mvc, dependencies

I'm developing a Spring app on Maven, and facing a seemingly duplicate dependency problem. In addition to mail.jar, I have javax.activation in activation.jar as well as jdk that's throwing the below exception:

```
javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: Unable to locate provider for protocol: smtp
    at javax.mail.Session.getProvider(Session.java:229)
    at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:338)
    at com.ace.amadeus.service.impl.EmailServiceImpl.send(EmailServiceImpl.java:75)
    at com.ace.amadeus.controller.MasterPricerController.index(MasterPricerController.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:421)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:313)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I successfully removed activation.jar by adding an exclusion to pom.xml as below, however, the exception doesn't seem to go.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
                        <exclusions>
                                <exclusion>
                                        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                                </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Now I'm wondering if it is possible to exclude the dependencies brought in by jdk.
Would that be possible?? [image]

Thanks for help.
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [maven-duplicate-finder plugin](https://github.com/ning/maven-duplicate-finder-plugin) to help track down where class conflicts may be coming from in your project. This can help figure out where you need to add excludes. Also check out the [enforcer plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/extra-enforcer-rules/banDuplicateClasses.html) for failing your build if duplicate classes are found.

```
mvn com.ning.maven.plugins:maven-duplicate-finder-plugin:1.0.2:check
```

For your specific error it seems that you do need both javax.mail:mail and activation on your classpath. There are some [other](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=locate%20provider%20smtp) questions dealing with this specific error that may be of some help.

Comment: Wasn't exactly the solution, but got to know a useful tool. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you set the maven home and Java_home in environment variable. If your are running maven trough IDE. Specify the maven to be used.

In eclipse :

preference->maven->Installation. Add the Maven path which you set as maven home.

Comment: Those are all in place. The whole application is running except for this error regarding email.